# How to #include "file.cpp"

Tags: c++

I must include file in .cpp format.

For test i create some file with sample content
1. file

```
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "kod.cpp"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int x=42;
   std::cout << x <<std::endl;
   std::cout << asd(x) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

2. file

```
kod.h
#ifndef KOD_H
#define KOD_H

class kod
{
    public:
        void asd(int);
    protected:
};

#endif
```

3. file

```
kod.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "kod.h"   
int asd(int a){
    return ++a; 
}
```

I have not idea why it dosen't work. I recieved errors from Dev-C++ 5.11

```
kod.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `asd(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.win    recipe for target 'Projekt5.exe' failed
```

How I can repair this app. I must use #define "kod.cpp" in main.cpp

Thank's for all advices
Regards

Comment: dont include `.cpp` files.

Comment: *Don't* include `*.cpp` files. Include header files only.

Comment: _"I must include file in .cpp format."_ Why do you need this actually? That's just wrong for most of any use cases.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `#include "kod.cpp"` with `#include "kod.h"` and make the function you define in the header a member function (at the moment it is just a free function with no relation to the class) by giving it this signature :

```
int kod::asd(int a){
```

And you have to make the signature in the cpp match the signature in the declaration. At the moment you declare it to be `void` but then on the definition it returns an `int`.